# scrapy project not executing

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed scrapy on my mac via pip and was able to succesfully install it, also installed latest python version.

So far so good.

I found this project that I'm trying to run :

https://github.com/anuvrat/soccerstats

There were some issues with deprecated code (ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead)

which I was able to fix,

however trying to run it I get these errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 150, in crawl
    crawler = self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 165, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 40, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: whoscored'
```

I executed it with: `scrapy crawl whoscored`

I have zero experience in python scrapy so i'm getting a bit lost here. Can anyone explain me what im doing wrong?

Comment: try it with the exact name `WhoScored` (capital S)

Comment: You can use [`scrapy list`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-list) inside a project to see which spiders you can run with `scrapy crawl`

Answer (score 2):

Spider names are case sensitive. `scrapy crawl WhoScored` should work.